# Pass multi-value parameter to ssrs

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a string of IDs that looks like strProjectIDs= '5123,5211,5896,1254,4785' and I'm trying to pass them directly to an ssrs report.  My report path looks like "http:///ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fPM%2fPacket&rs:Command=Render&ProjectIDs=" & strProjectIDs

I know that you can pass them through by adding on another (&ProjectIDs=) to the end of the url and get all of the reports at once, but my concern is that each time the user goes to generate this report there will be a different number of projects along with different projects in general (different IDs) so I don't want to have to hard code that in.

My question is if there is a way that when the string has more than one project ID, can this be broken up and automatically formatted into &ProjectIDs=4113&ProjectIDs=5223&ProjectIDs=5555....etc?

Thanks

Comment: You could just try it... or run a report with multiple project and see what is the url and replicate the same behavior.

Comment: when i run it right now i get a url with &ProjectIDs=5223,5226,5426,3652 etc, but nothing gets displayed.  When I manually enter in &ProjectIDs=5223&ProjectIDs=5226...etc it works like it should.  There is no difference anywhere else in the url

Comment: so why don't you do a replace on the string in vb?

Comment: Thanks dog.  It worked using the replace method